# Mysql limit just for the null rows of a certain column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have something like this `$SQL = "SELECT * FROM profile_comments WHERE name = '$username' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";` but I want to know if it's possible to limit the result just for the null rows of a certain column?

Exemple

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM profile_comments WHERE name = '$username' LIMIT table is NULL 5, 10";
```

profile_comments

```
id | parent_id |  name |    text    | datetime
-------------------------------------------------
 1 |   null    | Netra |  Bla bla   | 00.00.0000
 2 |    1      | Netra |  Bla bla   | 00.00.0000
 3 |    1      | Netra |  Bla bla   | 00.00.0000
 4 |   null    | Netra |  Bla bla   | 00.00.0000
 5 |    4      | Netra |  Bla bla   | 00.00.0000
```

Comment: I would read up on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184373/limit-on-a-condition-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pud that condition in the `WHERE` clause, not after the limit clause. How about this?

```
$SQL = "SELECT * 
        FROM profile_comments 
        WHERE name = '$username' AND  
              `table` is NULL 
        LIMIT 5, 10";
```

The answer:

`SELECT *
FROM   profile_comments
WHERE  PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   profile_comments
WHERE  PARENT_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY PARENT_ID;`

Comment: Sounds like the asker wants to limit on a condition (like limit the nulls, but don't limit the non-null values, but include both nulls and non-nulls). I found this, maybe it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184373/limit-on-a-condition-in-mysql

Comment: the problem is that in 'table' I have entry's that are not null and I want to show them.

Comment: @Stegrex yeah but he lack information regarding his question. so i assumed he only has error on his syntax :D

Comment: @Netra do you have example records in your table? :D it will help a lot.

Comment: @Netra so in your example, what would be your desired output? :)

Comment: @JohnWoo to limit the parent_id so I would have all the result that are not null and only one result that is null

Comment: @Netra is this what you want? [*See SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bb89/12)